# Clarification on sensor_msgs/Laserscan.msg

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wanting to extract features from laser data I have acquired using ROS from Pepper in the form of a sensor_msgs/Laserscan.msg.

However I am struggling to understand certain parts of the message.

Firstly, which might be obvious, am I right to assume that I should disregard data which are in not within the range specified by range_min and range_max, in this case, 0.1000000015 and 1.5 metres, respectively?

Also, I am wanting to plot this data, so that I can get a visualization the field of view of the laser (possible wrong terminology). Ie where the laser beams managed to reached in relation to the actual robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269004/clarification-on-sensor_msgs/laserscan.msg/) by [apples92](https://answers.ros.org/users/31596/apples92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Firstly, which might be obvious, am I right to assume that I should disregard data which are in not within the range specified by range_min and range_max, in this case, 0.1000000015 and 1.5 metres, respectively?

Yes, that's the convention.

> Also, I am wanting to plot this data, so that I can get a visualization the field of view of the laser (possible wrong terminology). Ie where the laser beams managed to reached in relation to the actual robot.

There is a plugin to view `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` in [Rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q198843, and the [sensor_msgs/LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2